# How can I make copy/paste work after using below code?

Tags: excel, vba

I used a code below which deactivates specific visual conditions for excel when I change workbook. But this code make copying information cells to another workbook impossible. How can I get both features at the same time or how should I modify my code?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "show.toolbar(""Ribbon"",True)"

Application.DisplayFormulaBar = True

Application.DisplayScrollBars = True

ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = True

Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: `deactivates  specific visual conditions` What conditions? I do not see any...

Comment: This code activae default excel parts (scrollbars, statusbars etc.) when I open new workbook. I am using this codes because the reverse version of this code run when I activate my main workbook. I was tried to hide all default parts in my main excel file while not changing anything for other excel files which can be open at the same time with my main file.

Comment: Ok. But my question still stands... What conditions? Which code? Without seeing that, we can tell you where the problem is. The code in the question will not prevent a user from copying and pasting.

Comment: When i delete above mentioned code I am able to easily copy from my main file to another. I understand that this code doesn't seem preventive for copying but it does. My question exactly is about why when I delete this code copying work bu otherwise not. Visual conditions I meant hiding/showing  the formulabar, scrollbar etc.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should change the reference to *which* workbook you want to change.

```
Dim blah As Workbook

Set blah = Workbooks.Open("blah.xlsm")
```

Then use blah for whatever. On a related note, ThisWorkbook refers to where the code is running, ActiveWorkbook refers to the currently active workbook.